# Deletion of multiple records from lots of tables from the database using a stored procedure

Tags: sql

There are 100 tables in my database and I have over 300 records to be deleted from some, more or all of these tables in a go. How can we achieve that?

Comment: With `DELETE`s. Good luck!

Comment: At this point you can maybe drop the database and recreate

Comment: It depends on which database you use (because "stored procedure" in e.g. MS SQL Server looks quite different from one in e.g. Oracle). Are those 100 tables *all* tables in that schema? Are those 300 rows all rows in those tables, or should you apply WHERE condition which will cause only a subset to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Use the query: -

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

If you want to delete then you can use delete query multiple times.